# two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that they are ***identical*** are not ***same***

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Hope this is not a duplicate.

I was trying to construct an example of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that they are ***identical*** but are not ***same***, i.e.

$P \{X \in A\} = P\{Y \in A\} \forall A \in B$ where $B$ is the Borel sigma-algebra but $P\{X=Y\} \neq 1$.

I've tried but not been able to come up with an answer.

Comment: What you are really asking is for two random variable that are not the same but have the same distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take, for example,
$$
P(X=1/2)=P(X=-1/2)=1/2
$$
and $Y=-X$.

Comment: @PhilJones $P\{X=-X\}=0$. $X$ cannot be equal to $-X$.